Javascript Event Listeners stopped working
I have a chat database that I am monitoring for new comments, this worked fine until quite recently where all event listener pages stopped working.
Here's the page I load in the browser:
<script>
var source = new EventSource('mychat.cfm');

source.addEventListener('message', function(e){

    document.body.innerHTML = e.data + document.body.innerHTML;

});



  function select(id,style) {
    //set the question live and turn off any others
    document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(item) {
  item.className = 'option';
})

        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        div.classList.replace("option", style);
        console.log(div);
    //
    }


</script>

And this is the page it calls:
<cfcontent type="text/event-stream">
<script>
  function select(id,style) {

        var div = document.getElementById(id);

        div.classList.replace("option", style);
        //setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 300);
        return false;
    }
 </script>

<CFquery datasource="chat" name="topmesg" >
SELECT max(id) as topid FROM chats where  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY) <= timestamp;
</cfquery>
<cfset topid=#topmesg.topid#-10>
<cfoutput>#topid#</cfoutput>

<cfsetting requesttimeout="800">

<cffunction name="sendData">

<cfoutput>data:<b>#author#</b>  |   #dateTimeFormat(Dateadd("h",1,mesg.timestamp), "ddd dd mmm - h:nn a")# <br> #mesg.message#</cfoutput>
<cfflush>
</cffunction>
<cfset fromDate = Now()>
<cfset toDate = DateAdd("n", 30 , Now())>
<cfloop from="#fromDate#" to="#toDate#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,1)#">
<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>
<CFquery datasource="chat" name="mesg" maxrows="10">
SELECT * FROM chats  where id > #topid#  order by id desc limit 0,11;
</cfquery>
<cfloop query="mesg">

    <cfset sendData()>
    <cfset topid=#id#>
</cfloop>

    <cfthread action="sleep" duration="1000"/>
<cfflush>
</cfloop>

As I said this all worked fine until la few weeks back, after working for a couple years.
I'm running:
OS: Linux (4.14.252-131.483.amzn1.x86_64)
Java Version: 64bit 1.8.0_92 (Oracle Corporation) 64bit
Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.35
Lucee Version: 6.0.0.585

Is your CFML page sending the messages as expected? Are there any errors in your JS console?

Rewriting the entire document.body.innerHTML will lose all dynamic changes to the DOM, so all event listeners are lost.
